# JavaScript: wait for every asynchronous call finished

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to load data from multiple sources and want to continue processing only after all data being loaded. Here is my code:

```
var tables = [];
$http
    .get('/tables')
    .then(function (response) {
        _.each(response.data, function (table) {
            tables.push(table);
        });
    })
    // get detail data
    .then(function () {
        _.each(tables, function (table) {
            $http.get('/tables/' + table)
                .success(function (data) {
                    process(data);
                });
        });
    })
    .then(function () {
        // after everything loaded
        // run this function
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
.then(function () {
    return $q.all(_.map(tables, function (table) {
        return $http.get('/tables/' + table)
        .success(process);
    });
})
```

Unrelated to the main part of your question, but note that you don't need to define an all new anonymous function for `.success` if you're just going to pass the parameter into `process()`.

See also: [$q promise with Underscore _each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671760/q-promise-with-underscore-each)