# underscore _.each and promise

Tags: underscore.js, promise

This is probably a classical problem but I'm having an hard time to find a proper answer.

```
var total_debit = {}; 
_.each(somearray, function(x) {
    if(!total_credit[b.currency]) {
          total_credit[b.currency] = 0;
    }
    // total_debit["usd"] HAS BEEN INITIALIZED!
    total_debit["usd"] += x
});

_.each(total_debit, function(td) {
    // do some stuff
});
```

The problem is that the second _.each is not iterating, considerating total_debit is still empty.

I tried to use a Promise but I probably implemented it the wrong way cause it's not working.

If anyone could lead me to the right way to implement the Promise for this specific use case I'll be eternally grateful.

Comment: it doesn't look like you closed the first _.each(); your question is also not entirely clear. Maybe this post will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671760/q-promise-with-underscore-each

Comment: badly write on stackoverflow but correctly write in my code, I corrected it, thanks, any idea otherwise ?

Comment: are you sure you want to be using an array? If you use a named index, with an array, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object. So, why not just use an obj. Maybe a plunkr or fiddle demonstrating what you are trying to accomplish would help.?

Comment: WTH are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the second `_.each` is not iterating, considerating `total_debit` is still empty.

There is nothing in that array indeed. It's `length` is still zero. The only thing is that it has a `.usd` property now (with accumulated `x`s from `somearray`).
The problem is that you are [abusing arrays](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) here. Underscore detects that you are using an array, and tries to iterate it (over all integer keys from `0` to `.length`). But there are no such properties.
Just use an object instead (`var total_debit = {};`) and underscore will treat it as a "map" type of collection, enumerating all keys including `.usd`.

> I tried to use a Promise but I probably implemented it the wrong way cause it's not working.

There is absolutely no reason to use promises here. Nothing in your code (at least in the part you've shown) is asynchronous.

Comment: The array has been initialized I specified it clearly. I modified the code to show you.

Comment: Yeah whatever (there no edit to your question?), but it is still not used as an array.

Comment: just edited it sorry
Whatever it is used as an array or an object it doesn't change anything to my problem.
I agree that conceptually I should declare an object but it doesn't change the problem at all.

Comment: @FrançoisRichard: Well, if you *did declare it as an object*, then that might not change the problem but would actually solve it.

Comment: wow  O_o but why ?  _.each is working with both array and object , just tested it, it didn't change anything, I updated the post with an object declaration

Comment: apparently this is synchronous so I'll look for the dumb thing I've done then come back here write the dumb thing, upvote your post and down my own dumb question... damn