# Using data from one async API call to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a question in regards to asynchronous data calls in AngularJS.

The issue is that I will be recieving multiple objects in an array from one API call, and I will have to extend those objects with data from a different API call.

I was thinking of having nested async calls, but my logic falls a bit short in terms of how this would work with the $q service. I have a service which will return the object which has been extended with the second call so I can use this in a controller for display in a view.

The first API call returns some parameters which I need for the second API call in order to get the relevant data for which I will return back to the controller.

I will have to loop inside the first call so I can then run the second API call inside of that, but how am I going to return this back to my controller? I cannot resolve when the first loop has been run, because well, it explains itself.

What is the go-to solution for something like this?

Edit, my issue in pseudo-javascript:

```
returnListOfStuff().then(function (data) {
    var result = data.Result;

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var dataForListItem = null;

        returnDataForListItem(result[i].ID).then(function (data) {
            dataForListItem = data;
        });

        for (prop in dataForListItem[0]) {
            result[i].prop = dataForListItem[0][prop];
        }
    }

    return result;
});
```

As is apparent, this won't work, considering it will only fetch the results from the first call `returnListOfStuff()`, because what is happening inside the for loop is not yet resolved. I can't really figure out how to do this with `$q.all()`, because I don't have the parameters from the `returnListOfStuff` function yet

Comment: Without your code its hard to judge what your problem is, but this sounds like a duplicate of [$q promise with loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25671760/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi added some pseudo-code to describe the problem closer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't really figure out how to do this with `$q.all()`, because I don't have the parameters from the `returnListOfStuff` function yet

You can just do it in the `then` callback where you have them.

You can return the promise that `$q.all` yields from the callback to get a promise for the propped up `result`.

```
returnListOfStuff().then(function (data) {
    var result = data.Result;
    return $q.all(result.map(function(resultItem) {
        return returnDataForListItem(resultItem.ID).then(function (data) {
            for (prop in data[0]) {
                resultItem[prop] = data[0][prop];
            }
            return resultItem;
        });
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) for this:

```
var loadQ = [];
var dataForListItem = null;
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    loadQ.push(returnDataForListItem(result[i].ID));
}

$q.all(loadQ).then(function(values){
    dataForListItem = values;//or values[0], I dnt known Your data structure;
});
```

If You will have problem with `i` value, try use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    (function(e) {
        loadQ.push(returnDataForListItem(result[e].ID));
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: I will try to do this approach and report back. Thank you, didn't know I could do this.

Comment: @NicT and if possible, add `returnDataForListItem` code in your question, for more professional help.